# where does BIOS store com port enable?

Tags: configuration, serial-port, dos, bios

My goal is to write a program in DOS that will disable COM2 in BIOS.  Any solution must work in DOS.

Where does the BIOS store the Enable / Disable state for peripherals such as serial ports?

I have examined the CMOS and nothing other than the clock data changes when I enable the port in BIOS and reboot.

The CPU board is an Advantech PCA6028, a single-host board with an AMI BIOS circa 2019.

Comment: If you want disable the COM port so that on subsequent reboots the BIOS doesn't enable it then you're going to have reverse engineer the BIOS because there's no standard location where it stores this information.  If you just want to disable the port in DOS to prevent anything using it until the next reboot then you can look for the Super I/O's datasheet (NCT 6776D) which should document how to enable and disable its serial ports.

Comment: Thank you @RossRidge.  I had read online that there is technically nothing wrong with manufacturers moving all the settings into the BIOS flash and that they are left in CMOS for largely historical reasons.  It is an IRQ conflict and I don't think it can be fixed easily after boot, but thanks for the Super I/O #.  I think I must do exactly as the BIOS does, as you allude.  It's that or write a procedure for semi-technical operators to connect a monitor and keyboard to a normally headless computer and change the BIOS.

Comment: From the sounds of things disabling the serial port wouldn't accomplish anything. Serial ports don't generate interrupts unless programmed to do so, and the BIOS does not program them to do so.